# Can a phpMyAdmin data entry form enter data in linked tables?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm very familiar with using phpMyAdmin to create new entries in a single MySQL table. But is it possible to create a data entry form that will enter data in linked tables?

Example: a 'Customer' file linked to a 'Purchases' file linked to a 'Products' file?

Any tips and/or pointers to documentation appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not part of phpMyAdmin's features but you can request this feature. Not sure how it could be done for three tables, but it might be feasible with one linked table.